# Jquery Jscroll.js gives a blank page

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscroll

I use this plugin : jScroll (http://jscroll.com). It's a jQuery plugin for infinite scrolling. After the last element it loads the next one via the pagination next.

html Example :

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <a class="page-link" href="page/2">
    </div>
</div>
```

At document ready :

```
$('.scroll').jscroll({
    pagingSelector: '.pagination',
    nextSelector: '.page-link:last',
    contentSelector : '.items',
    loadingHtml: 'loading...'
});
```

I use this similar code on 2 differents websites. One of them works perfectly, the other one gives a blank page.

I mean, when i scroll to the bottom, i see "loading..." and it quicly disapears. The next page "/page/2" works perfectly into the browser when i manualy type the url

It seems to be a cache problem but i don't know how i can resolve it.

it will be great if you have any ideas

Thanks

Comment: Check the network tab in the browser, what does it say? do you see anything appearing when you scroll?

Comment: In console, jQuery works, all divs from the plugin are created but tthe XHR response from "GET http://[...]/page/2" is empty. I don't understand why...the url works prefectly in the url bar. Not from jQuery loading

Comment: other any ideas?

Comment: add it to a server so I can see it and i'll tell you how to fix it